# Fix to not being able to press Up+Down on PS3 Konami Dance Pad on PC

Tags: controllers, dance-dance-revolution, stepmania

I am unable to press Up+Down or Left+Right at the same time. I am using a PS3 Konami Dance pad connected to my computer via USB. Everything else works fine, and this seems to be a common issue.

Comment: This question looks more like a ticket to report a bug than a question itself o.o

Comment: I don't think it's a pad problem so much as it's a controller issue.  The scenario of using two opposite directions at the exact same time is something that comes up pretty darn rarely.  There may not BE a fix.

Comment: Wasn't sure where to ask this since I'm not sure if Konami support even exists for their old Dance Pads or if they even support using the PS3 Dance Pad on the PC.

The scenario of using two opposite directions does rarely come up. However for Dance Dance Revolution and other similar games, it's very common.

Comment: There seems to be a work-around of sorts that uses a button remapping program and a custom configuration file on the [Stepmania forums](http://www.stepmania.com/forums/input-adapters-and-controllers/show/329#post1528). If someone else wants to make that into an answer, they are free to, as I do not have the dance-pad in question (or even Stepmania) to test and confirm this.

Comment: I tried the method you posted and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Darn. That was the most likely solution that didn't involve re-wiring/soldering the dance pad I could find.

Comment: It wasn't obvious from the post, but for anyone else, that solution remaps the dancepad buttons to ASDW, so assign the inputs to ASDW in Stepmania.